# UIImageview not showing in simulator

Tags: ios, swift, uiimageview, uiimage, ios-simulator

I'm writing the following code

```
var imageViewObject = UIImageView(frame:CGRectMake(0, 0, 512, 512))
var img = UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath)
imageViewObject.layer.borderWidth = 1.0
imageViewObject.layer.borderColor = UIColor.blackColor().CGColor
imageViewObject.image = img
imageViewObject.contentMode = UIViewContentMode.ScaleToFill
view.addSubview(imageViewObject)
print(imageViewObject.image?.size)
```

The imgPath is the path of a .png image that is saved in the documents directory with size 512,512. 
The first time that i run the app to simulator the image is showing properly and it prints 512,512.At the second run it only shows up the border and the last line prints nil.

What am I missing?

Comment: check that your omg(path) contains image or not

Comment: Check your "imgPath" contains path of image or not ? I think your path is empty.

Comment: The 1st time imgPath is "/Users/pmdevios/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/C60344FC-7B12-453F-81D3-E873FCF07EA7/data/Containers/Data/Application/74F921DC-3031-4424-95E8-149237157AE5/Documents/ButtonIcons/Label.png" and img is not null.The second time i run the app imgPath is the same but UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath) returns nil....When I delete all the files from documents folder and delete user defaults and run again the image shows up again.What is happening??

Comment: if you are run in simulator the path is every time changes . so don't worry about that , check that your path is empty or value

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik Thank you very much!!!I didn't know that the path is changing so the first time that i was downloading the image i was saving in sqlite the localpath and i was using this at UIImage(contentsOfFile: imgPath). Now it is ok.Thank you again for the tip.

Comment: If you want post an answer to accept it.